# Spring+Camel: Context initialization failed: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I'm creating dynamically about 600 Camel CXF-endpoints and routes during application start-up. I have a problem with out of memory when creating endpoints in that way. I need to create many enpoints during start-up.
When I create only a few it works fine. The problem is when I'm creating many of them.

```
CxfSpringEndpoint cxfEndpoint1 = new CxfSpringEndpoint();
        cxfEndpoint1.setAddress(address);
        cxfEndpoint1.setEndpointNamespace(namespace);
        cxfEndpoint1.setEndpointName(QName.valueOf(endpointPort));
        cxfEndpoint1.setServiceLocalName(serviceName);
        cxfEndpoint1.setWsdlURL(wsdl);
        cxfEndpoint1.setCamelContext(camelContext);
        cxfEndpoint1.setDataFormat(DataFormat.MESSAGE);
        camelContext.addEndpoint(entpointName1, cxfEndpoint1);

CxfSpringEndpoint cxfEndpoint2 = new CxfSpringEndpoint();
...

from(entpointName1)
                .to("log:input")
                .transform(body().regexReplaceAll("a", "b")) 
                .to(entpointName2)     
                .to("log:input");
```

I get following error:

```
15:25:50,367 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-2) Context initialization failed: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at org.apache.xerces.util.SymbolTable$Entry.<init>(SymbolTable.java:400)
at org.apache.xerces.util.SymbolTable.addSymbol(SymbolTable.java:230)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.scanQName(XMLEntityScanner.java:614)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:129)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1653)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:324)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:845)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:768)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:108)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:230)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:285)
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection$2.run(XmlSchemaCollection.java:749) [xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar:]
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection$2.run(XmlSchemaCollection.java:747) [xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar:]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.parseDoPriv(XmlSchemaCollection.java:747) [xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar:]
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.read(XmlSchemaCollection.java:716) [xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar:]
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.resolveXmlSchema(SchemaBuilder.java:706) [xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar:]
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleImport(SchemaBuilder.java:538) [xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar:]
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleSchemaElementChild(SchemaBuilder.java:1516) [xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar:]
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleXmlSchemaElement(SchemaBuilder.java:659) [xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar:]
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.build(SchemaBuilder.java:157) [xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar:]
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.read(XmlSchemaCollection.java:508) [xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar:]
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.read(XmlSchemaCollection.java:717) [xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar:]
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.resolveXmlSchema(SchemaBuilder.java:706) [xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar:]
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleImport(SchemaBuilder.java:538) [xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar:]
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleSchemaElementChild(SchemaBuilder.java:1516) [xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar:]
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleXmlSchemaElement(SchemaBuilder.java:659) [xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar:]
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.build(SchemaBuilder.java:157) [xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar:]
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.read(XmlSchemaCollection.java:508) [xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar:]
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.read(XmlSchemaCollection.java:717) [xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar:]
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.resolveXmlSchema(SchemaBuilder.java:706) [xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar:]
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleImport(SchemaBuilder.java:538) [xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar:]
```

Jboss configuration:

```
 JAVA_OPTS: -XX:+TieredCompilation -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms1g -Xmx2500M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

Comment: I've checked I can add successfully about 100 endpoints (50 routes), when I try to add more I get error.